# How are functions $\hat{f}: T \to Y^T$ equivalent to functions of the form $f: T \times T \to Y$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was reading a paper on ArXiv and the author made the above assertion. $T,Y$ are sets, $f,\hat{f}$ are regular set-functions, and $Y^T$ is the set of all functions $T\to Y$.

He supplemented it with the following:

> Every $\hat{f}$ can be converted to a function $f$ where
>   $f(t,t')=\hat{f}(t')(t)\in Y$.

I seem to be having trouble understanding this "proof" he's supplying that the two are equivalent. My problems are:

1. $f(t,t')$ maps $(t,t')$ to an element $y\in Y$, yet $\hat{f}(t')$ maps $t'$ to an entire set.
2. What does $\hat{f}(t')(t)$ mean? There was never an established "operation" or anything. Does the author intend to say $\hat{f}(t') \hat{f}(t)$? But even this makes no sense.

For those who wish to see the paper, [here's the link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305282.pdf). These assertions are made at the bottom of page 2.

Comment: search of currying and uncurrying, or also functions with parameters

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek: If $X,Y,Z$ are sets, then there is a bijection between $Z^{Y\times X}$ and $(Z^Y)^X$.

Comment: I'll look more into currying for now then a bit into your assertion @Tortoise, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is not that $f$ and $\hat f$ have the same outputs on the same inputs, or that $\hat f(t')$ gives you the same $y$ that $f(t,t')$ does. The claim is that

- there is an operation $\hat -$ that takes $f:T\times T\to Y$ to $\hat f:T\to Y^T$,
- $f(t,t')=\hat f(t')(t)$,
- and $\hat -$ is a bijection.

Note that $\hat f(t)$ doesn't map just to "a whole set", but specifically to a function $T\to Y$. The $\hat -$ operation is defined by $t\mapsto (t'\mapsto f(t,t'))$. We can also define an operation, say $\breve -$, that is the inverse of $\hat -$; for $g:T\to Y^T$, $\breve g := \langle t,t'\rangle\mapsto g(t')(t)$. You can check for yourself that $\hat{\breve{g}}=g$ and $\breve{\hat{f}}=f$. This is all the "conversion" above means.